# SQL insert statement from another table loop

Tags: sql, loops, insert

I am trying to take values from a table and insert them into another table. However, there is one database column that needs to increase by 1 value each time. This value though is not an identity insert column, the value comes from another table. There is another db column that acts as a counter. I wrote a couple of things but it just isnt helping:
(121 documents)

```
declare @count int;
set @count=0
while @count<=121
begin
insert into cabinet..DOCUMENT_NAMES_ROBBY (TAG,TAGORDER,ACTIVE,QUEUE,REASON,FORM,DIRECT_VIEW,GLOBAL,FU_SIGN,
SIGN_X,SIGN_Y,SIGN_W,SIGN_H,ANNOTATE,doctype_id,CODE,DOC_TYPE,SET_ID,SUSPEND_DELAY,Text_Editing,Restrict_Viewing,Viewing_Expire,
Viewing_Period,DocHdrLength,DocFtrLength,DocRuleId,Outbound,SigQueue,SigReason) select TAG,TAGORDER,ACTIVE,QUEUE,REASON,FORM,
DIRECT_VIEW,GLOBAL,FU_SIGN,
SIGN_X,SIGN_Y,SIGN_W,SIGN_H,ANNOTATE,(select nextid from cabinet..Wfe_NextValue where Name='documents')+1, CODE,DOC_TYPE,'2',SUSPEND_DELAY,Text_Editing,Restrict_Viewing,Viewing_Expire,
Viewing_Period,DocHdrLength,DocFtrLength,DocRuleId,Outbound,SigQueue,SigReason from cabinet..document_names where SET_ID ='1'
update cabinet..Wfe_NextValue set NextID=NextID+1 where Name='documents'
set @count=@count+1
end
```

That database column is the doctype_id. Above obviously comes out wrong and puts like 14,000 rows in the table. Basically I want to take every single entry from document_names and put it in document_names_robby...except the doctype_id column should take the value from wfe_nextvalue +1, while at the same time increasing that number in that table by 1 BEFORE inserting the next document name into document_Names_Robby. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Many popular databases support [sequences](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-sequence.html). For the sequence, there is a function *nextval* that returns the sequence value and increments the sequence counter and *currval* that returns the latest previously returned value, also you can set the initial value and increment. Sequences are thread safe when storing counters in the table column is not.

Rewrite your code using sequences.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using **SQL Server** database. Use `IDENTITY` function

```
SELECT *, IDENTITY(int, 1,1) AS IDCol FROM Cabinet.DocumentNames INTO #Tab1 WHERE Set_Id = '1';    
insert into cabinet..DOCUMENT_NAMES_ROBBY (TAG,TAGORDER,ACTIVE,QUEUE,REASON,FORM,DIRECT_VIEW,GLOBAL,FU_SIGN,
SIGN_X,SIGN_Y,SIGN_W,SIGN_H,ANNOTATE,doctype_id,CODE,DOC_TYPE,SET_ID,SUSPEND_DELAY,Text_Editing,Restrict_Viewing,Viewing_Expire,
Viewing_Period,DocHdrLength,DocFtrLength,DocRuleId,Outbound,SigQueue,SigReason) 
SELECT * FROM #Tab1;
DROP TABLE #Tab1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @count int;
set @count=0
declare @nextId int;
select @nextId= nextid from cabinet..Wfe_NextValue where Name='documents'
while @count<=121
begin
insert into cabinet..DOCUMENT_NAMES_ROBBY         (TAG,TAGORDER,ACTIVE,QUEUE,REASON,FORM,DIRECT_VIEW,GLOBAL,FU_SIGN,
        SIGN_X,SIGN_Y,SIGN_W,SIGN_H,ANNOTATE,doctype_id,CODE,DOC_TYPE,SET_ID,SUSPEND_DELAY,Text_Edi    ting,Restrict_Viewing,Viewing_Expire,
Viewing_Period,DocHdrLength,DocFtrLength,DocRuleId,Outbound,SigQueue,SigReason) select     TAG,TAGORDER,ACTIVE,QUEUE,REASON,FORM,
DIRECT_VIEW,GLOBAL,FU_SIGN,
SIGN_X,SIGN_Y,SIGN_W,SIGN_H,ANNOTATE,(select nextid from cabinet..Wfe_NextValue where     Name='documents')+1,     CODE,DOC_TYPE,'2',SUSPEND_DELAY,Text_Editing,Restrict_Viewing,Viewing_Expire,
Viewing_Period,DocHdrLength,DocFtrLength,DocRuleId,Outbound,SigQueue,SigReason from     cabinet..document_names where SET_ID ='1'
set @count=@count+1
end
update cabinet..Wfe_NextValue set NextID=NextID+121 where Name='documents'
```

Comment: Ravindra, i did that:
SELECT *, IDENTITY(int, 1,1) AS IDCol FROM Cabinet.Document_Names INTO cabinet..document_names_robby WHERE Set_Id = '1';    
insert into cabinet..DOCUMENT_NAMES_ROBBY (TAG,TAGORDER,ACTIVE,QUEUE,REASON,FORM,DIRECT_VIEW,GLOBAL,FU_SIGN,
SIGN_X,SIGN_Y,SIGN_W,SIGN_H,ANNOTATE,doctype_id,CODE,DOC_TYPE,'2',SUSPEND_DELAY,Text_Editing,Restrict_Viewing,Viewing_Expire,
Viewing_Period,DocHdrLength,DocFtrLength,DocRuleId,Outbound,SigQueue,SigReason) 
SELECT * FROM cabinet..document_names_robby;
DROP TABLE cabinet..document_names_robby;

Comment: but got 
Msg 177, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
The IDENTITY function can only be used when the SELECT statement has an INTO clause.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near '2'.

and the other comment left by user produced over 14000 rows like mine originally did